# Android Studio Layout Preview Default Theme

Tags: android, android-studio

Maybe this is well known option in Android Studio but I couldn't find it and Google has not helped me with this :( Every time I open a layout preview in Android Studio it's applying Material.Light theme to every layout in my project and I need manually apply my own theme to see how it will look like in a real app. Does somebody know how to change default Material.Light theme to be my custom theme when previewing layout with Layout Previewer in Android Studio so I don't need to apply it manually every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed the theme in the manifest to you custom theme? Change theme in previewer after doing so.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Same problem here.

Comment: @Dr.jacky no :(

Answer (score 7):

Click here and change theme to your theme.

[image: Click here and change theme]

If you want a single theme to always open, give

`android:theme="@style/YourTheme"` in your `<application>` tag in Manifest file.

From next time onwards, when you create a new xml file, this will be your default theme.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question was if I can to set somewhere in the settings my custom theme for layout preview so I don't need to set it manually every time as you showed on the picture.

Comment: Try adding android:theme="@style/YourTheme" in your <application> tag in Manifest file and creating new xml files, it will open with Theme: YourTheme

Comment: I have tried this but no effect on Layout Preview :(

Comment: Try invalidating caches and restarting and creating new xml layouts. Sorry, but its working for me. Are you using the latest studio version?

Comment: If your layout is in a library module, you have to add the theme to the module AndroidManifest file.

Comment: It is not a solution. You have to set the splash theme in the app block of the Manifest to be able use the SplashScreen API

Comment: I dont want to change theme of my application. My default application theme is light. But every time i open any xml in the project, i need to manually switch to dark theme. Why this option is not persists until next switch?

Comment: This just does not work. It applies just to currently viewed layout, but not all layouts!

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide default theme on application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If you don't provide  `android:theme="@style/{themeName}` there will be added `Material.Light` default theme.

Please check example of code snippet from my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.iqall" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iqall_main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" <!--in Preview you will see this as default preview-->
        android:name=".IQallApp">
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It is not a solution. You have to set the splash theme in the app block of the Manifest to be able use the SplashScreen API

Answer (score 4):

In all your manifests (in all modules), set

```
<application android:theme="@Theme/mainTheme">
</application
```

If you use Splashscreen theme (official way)

in your App module,

```
 <application
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme">

 </application>
```

**AND RESTART Android Studio** (very important)

Comment: Could you provide the source/link to the "official way"?

Comment: @MatJB i speak about the splashscreen library, there is now an official way to create splashscreen https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: Unfortunately, your answers set a default theme for the **app**, the OP is asking for a way to set a default theme just for the **Design layout preview in Android Studio**, without the need to modify the app's default theme.

Comment: @MatJB Design Layout Preview use your default app theme. But, if your layout is in module library, it can't be finded.you must specify the default theme also in this library. (And don't forget to add tools:replace="android:theme" in you app module)

Comment: Thanks! Replaced a theme in all modules and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that android studio should always show the a particular theme for layout previews then in the XML file for that layout you can add `tools:theme="@style/Theme.App"`

This will only apply this theme for development viewing purposes automatically when a layout file is opened. So that you dont need to set the theme from, lets say starting splashsrceen theme (`Theme.Starting`) to actual app theme (`Theme.App`)

**Note: You need to add this to all your required layout XML files where you want `Theme.App` to be shown for XML layout file preview.**

example code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:theme="@style/Theme.App">
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

It must be set in the manifest, but wait there is a workaround. Use tools, then it will only effect the default theme in Android Studio Layout Preview

```
<application tools:theme="@style/RetailTheme">
```